# Template parameter dependant [[nodiscard]]

Tags: c++, attributes, c++17, nodiscard

I have a functional object which is a wrapper around another function:

```
template <typename FuncT>
class Wrapper
{
    private:
        FuncT funcToWrap;

    public:
        Wrapper(FuncT ftw) : funcToWrap(ftw){};

        template<typename ...ARG>
        typename std::result_of<FuncT(ARG&&...)>::type operator()(ARG&&... args){
            return funcToWrap(std::forward<ARG>(args)...);
        }
};

int main(){
    std::function<void()> testfunc = [](){ std::cout << "Test" << std::endl; };
    Wrapper<decltype(testfunc)> test{testfunc};
    test();
}
```

What I would like to do is to mark the `operator()` as `[[nodiscard]]` if the `std::result_of<FuncT(ARG&&...)>::type` is not `void`.

What I have noticed is that when I do put the `[[nodiscard]]` in case of the template evaluation of return type to `void`, it will simply get ignored by my compiler.

Is this the behaviour I can rely on, is it in any way standarized?

Comment: This is clearly [not guaranteed by the standard](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.attr.nodiscard), but I find no documentation from gcc or clang about void nodiscard :(

Comment: Yea, me neither, but for gcc version 7.4.0 it works, I was quite surprised actually that it does, thought I will need to template specialize for void return.

Comment: `std::result_of` is [deprecated in C++17 and removed in C++20](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of). Use `std::invoke_result` instead.

Comment: It appears to be unspecified by the standard. But honestly, I'd just put the attribute there and not fret. Attributes are non-binding hints to the compiler. So long as they are syntactically correct, they will not make an otherwise well-formed program into an ill-formed one.

Comment: I wonder if it should be reported as a documentation bug...

Comment: @YSC I will have a look on how to do it and try and ask on discussion group

Comment: Working around the lack of guarantees: https://wandbox.org/permlink/xAQvlhtB6CXU8YnV

Comment: @metalfox: You should post that as an answer

Comment: @Eric OK. Posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [[dcl.attr.nodiscard]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.attr.nodiscard#2):

> [ *Note:* A nodiscard call is a function call expression that calls a
>   function previously declared `nodiscard`, or whose return type is a
>   possibly cv-qualified class or enumeration type marked `nodiscard`.
>   Appearance of a nodiscard call as a potentially-evaluated
>   discarded-value expression is discouraged unless explicitly cast to
>   `void`. Implementations should issue a warning in such cases. This is
>   typically because discarding the return value of a nodiscard call has
>   surprising consequences. — *end note* ]

My reading of this paragraph gives that, given

```
[[nodiscard]] void f() {}
```

even

```
f();
```

should issue a warning. You have to explicitly cast to `void` as in

```
(void) f();
```

to suppress it. So no, this is not guaranteed by the standard.

It seems to me that the standard simply overlooked this subtlety.

Answer (score 2):

You can use SFINAE to select between two overloaded `operator ()`: one of them returning void, and another one for the rest of cases annotated with the `[[nodiscard]]` attribute:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template <typename FuncT>
class Wrapper
{
    private:
        FuncT funcToWrap;

    public:
        Wrapper(FuncT ftw) : funcToWrap(ftw) {}

        template <typename ...ARG, typename T = std::invoke_result_t<FuncT, ARG...>>
        std::enable_if_t<std::is_void_v<T>> operator()(ARG&&... args) {
            std::cout << "Test 1" << std::endl;
            return funcToWrap(std::forward<ARG>(args)...);
        }

        template <typename ...ARG, typename T = std::invoke_result_t<FuncT, ARG...>>
        [[nodiscard]] std::enable_if_t<!std::is_void_v<T>, T> operator()(ARG&&... args) {
            std::cout << "Test 2" << std::endl;
            return funcToWrap(std::forward<ARG>(args)...);
        }
};

int main() {
    auto testfunc1 = [] { };
    Wrapper test1{testfunc1};
    test1(); // <-- No warnings should be issued here

    auto testfunc2 = [] { return 0; };
    Wrapper test2{testfunc2};
    test2(); // <-- Warning issued here
}
```

Comment: The whole point of the question is that I didn't want to do the above. This is what I started with and was wondernig if I had to do it or if it was ok to drop sfinea and use  [[nodiscard]] void in such case.

Comment: @cerkiewny The title of the question and the “What I would like to do…” sentence do not suggest so. Anyway, I posted the answer because I was asked for. I can delete it if you think it is neither useful for other users.

Comment: It can stay, if someone gets there because of the doubts how to deal with the problem it is useful, however I am just marking that this doesn't answer my concerns, but it is related for sure